# How to split a column in a dataframe into multiple columns in python?

Tags: python, split, multiple-columns

The position of the "V" is not constant. The value before the "V" is not constant or it may be a 0 value. The "V" can also be a different letter. Need code

[image: Input]

```
ConcatenatedColumn
0.9147V2020-08-042020-06-092019-11-09
3.2F2020-09-112019-05-052020-10-12
```

[image: Output]

```
Rate    Indicator   Date 1  Date 2  Date 3
0.9147  V   2020-08-04  2020-06-09  2019-11-09
3.2 F   2020-09-11  2019-05-05  2020-10-12
```

Comment: How did it get that way? What does the original data look like? Perhaps you could have imported it better.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski the data was already imported, im trying to clean it up. Looks like it was a concatenated column and we just need to split it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution using Pandas and NumPy:

```py
# Process the dataframe
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Define the columns
rowName = np.arange(0,df.shape[0])
colName = ['Rate','Indicator','Date 1','Date 2','Date 3']

# Create new empty df
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=rowName, columns=colName)

# Process each concatenated column
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    # Get concatenated string
    rowText = df.ConcatenatedColumn[i]
    
    # Find rate and indicator
    for j in range(len(rowText)):
        if (rowText[j].isalpha()):           # isalpha checks for any character
            df2.at[i, 'Rate'] = rowText[0:j]
            df2.at[i, 'Indicator'] = rowText[j]
            remStr = rowText[j+1:]
    
    # Find the 3 dates
    lenDate = 10       # Assuming dates are in YYYY-MM-DD format
    df2.at[i, 'Date 1'] = remStr[0:lenDate]
    df2.at[i, 'Date 2'] = remStr[lenDate:(2*lenDate)]
    df2.at[i, 'Date 3'] = remStr[(2*lenDate):]
```

where `df` is your concatenated column data:

```
    ConcatenatedColumn
0   0.9147V2020-08-042020-06-092019-11-09
1   3.2F2020-09-112019-05-052020-10-12
```

and `df2` is your split column output:

```
    Rate     Indicator  Date 1      Date 2      Date 3
0   0.9147   V          2020-08-04  2020-06-09  2019-11-09
1   3.2      F          2020-09-11  2019-05-05  2020-10-12
```

**However, please note that I assumed the concatenated column contains 3 dates. If the number of dates varies, my code for the dates can be replaced with a while loop where the string is being constantly updated.**